# Pie Highchart Chart with multiple "ring's" around it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Among the http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ *Chart's* ,

which *Chart* is most appropriate in order to achieve a -

*circle which has two rings around it , such that each ring indicate the segmentation of its series out off its "total" - something like*  -

```
series: [{
            name: 'Browser share',
            total : 100
            data: [ 
                ['White',   70.0],
                ['Dark Gray', 20.0],
                ['Gray', 10.0]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Color',
            total : 100
            data: [
                ['Orange', 50],
                ['Null'  , 50]
            ]
        }
        ]
```

would give  - ring overlap another ring .

**Edit:**

I found this - http://jsfiddle.net/wjqrh/76/ , I want like this but with another ring overlap it .

Comment: You can add extra serie like here http://jsfiddle.net/wjqrh/83/

Comment: @SebastianBochan: exactly what I looked for ! you welcome to write it as an answer and I will accept it .

Comment: I added it as answer, feel free for vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add extra serie like here

```
series: [
            {
                name: '',
                data: [['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50]],
                size: '70%',
                innerSize: '60%',
                showInLegend: false
            },                {
                name: '',
                data: [['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50], ['a', 50]],
                size: '60%',
                innerSize: '55%',
                showInLegend: false
            }
        ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wjqrh/83

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for a doughnut chart. Highcharts supports this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Check out the [innerSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.innerSize) option for the plotOption:

```
plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: 80
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ae8Ac/

Comment: Something like this but without the round in the center , only the ring's around .